# Serve Gzipped js and css files web app under nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nginx, gzip

I ve a web app built with **Angular** (**angular-cli**)

To build my app , i am running `ng build --configuration=production`

I ve been todl that gzipping action was removed from this process from angular-cli , So using a specific npm package **"Gzipper"** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzipper

I was used to both build and compress my outputed files using one combinated command :

`ng build --configuration=production && && gzipper src/main/webapp/dist --log`

*my output file are like this :*

- scriptOne.js
- scriptOne.js.gzip
- scriptTwo.js
- scriptTwo.js.gzip
- myStyle.css
- myStyle.css.gzip

Now under my **nginx.conf.file** :
i ve put this config :

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    more_clear_headers "Server";

    gzip  on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

    server {
       ...
    }
```

Even with all this :  under any browser , it throws me a **404 not found files**
Seems that it can't see those gzip files and my app cannot be served

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `gzip_static on;`

```
gzip  on;
gzip_static on;
```

> The ngx_http_gzip_static_module module allows sending precompressed files with the “.gz” filename extension instead of regular files.